# Why isn't my programming performing correctly? The if statement isn't being evaluated and it straightway jumps to the else statement in Python

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

When I am trying to input any value into op, always the else statement executes.

What is the problem here? I am new to programming

```
print "Basic Calculator"
print "Options:"
print "For addition, type add"
print "For subtraction, type sub"
print "For multiplication, type mul"
print "For division, type div"

op = raw_input()
num1 = raw_input("Enter first number: ")
num2 = raw_input("Enter second number: ")

if op == 'sum':
    print "The sum is: ", num1 + num2
elif op == 'sub':
    if num1 > num2:
        print "The subtraction is: ", num1 - num2
    else:
        print "The subtraction is: ", num1 - num2
elif op == 'mul':
    print "The product is: ", num1 * num2
elif op == 'div':
    print "The division is: ", num1 / num2
else:
    print "You entered an incorrect operation"
```

Comment: It works just perfect for me :)

Comment: I didn't see any issue here except the type casting. Provide the input you have given and the respective output

Comment: How are you **proving** that an equality operation isn't evaluated? I mean, normally that would require something like adding a function, ie. `def compare(val, target): print "Comparing %r and %r" % (val, target); return val == target` and then putting that function in your `if` statements and looking for the side effect (the print statement).

Comment: BTW, `print "You entered an incorrect operation: %r" % (op,)` would make it easier to diagnose why your earlier comparisons were failing.

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine if you type the operation you wants first then the two numbers, also you need to cast the numbers typped as integers :

```
print "Basic Calculator"
print "Options:"
print "For addition, type add"
print "For subtraction, type sub"
print "For multiplication, type mul"
print "For division, type div"

op = raw_input("Enter the operation wanted (add, sub, mul, div): ")
num1 = raw_input("Enter first number: ")
num2 = raw_input("Enter second number: ")

intNum1 = int(num1)
intNum2 = int(num2)
if op == 'sum':
    print "The sum is: ", intNum1 + intNum2
elif op == 'sub':
    if intNum1 > intNum2:
        print "The subtraction is: ", intNum1 - intNum2
    else:
        print "The subtraction is: ", intNum1 - intNum2
elif op == 'mul':
    print "The product is: ", intNum1 * intNum2
elif op == 'div':
    print "The division is: ", intNum1 / intNum2
else:
    print "You entered an incorrect operation"
```

[Try it here](http://pythonfiddle.com/)